# How to avoid the duplicate rows for total

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7

report

```
id value

01 100
02 200
01 100
04 200
01 100
```

From the above report i want to avoid the duplicate rows

Created Formula in supress like this

```
{id} <> Previous({id})
```

The above formula is working in crystal report which is hiding the duplicate rows, but
in running and grant total it is showing duplicate row total also

Running total Group by id is shwoing like this

```
id value

01 100
------
   300

02 200
-------
   200

04 200
-------
   200
```

I don't want to show duplicate value total

Expected Output

id value

```
01 100
------
   100 'Avoided duplicate row for total 

02 200
-------
   200

04 200
-------
   200
```

How to do this in crystal report

Need crystal report help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

Add a running total -> Add id as field to summarize then in below evaluate section mark on changing of group and then in rest section use a formula check the screen shot

[image]

add your formula here in formula editor i.e.

```
{id} <> Previous({id})
```

and your desired result will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Group by ID and make your running total evaluate and reset on change of group.